# Desktop Application Configuration Management

Tags: configuration

There are many tools for managing the configuration of infrastructure like Chef, Puppet etc But are there any tools that aid with the pain of managing the configuration of desktop applications?

So, as an example, you have an environment with 150+ different legacy desktop applications (most internally developed with some 20+ years old). Each of those applications can run in at least 3 different environments (eg Dev, Test, Live), some can have many more environments. Some applications can be running with different versions. With all of these variants you end up with hundreds if not thousands of configuration files. How can you centrally manage the configuration of the applications so that you can handle scenarios such as "Database server xyz is being replaced with zyx, we need to repoint all relevant application configurations".

The answer we have currently is to amend the apps so that at start up they call out to some form of central configuration management server, announcing the apps name, version and the environment it's in and the central server responds with the correct configuration. But is this the right approach and if so, why can't I find any off the shelf products that would handle this, surely others have this issue as well?

There are other issues as well around handling different configuration types, such as registry settings, ini files, config files, etc., but they can all be managed with the data returned from the central server. There are also issues around the dependency on the configuration server, but they can be handled with caching of configuration and other techniques.